# Check a solution for derivative inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis

Trying to solve the following problem:

---

Let $f : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, and assume that
$$\left | f'(x) - f'(y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |$$
for all $x, y \in (a, b)$. Show that
$$\left | f(x) - f(y) - f'(x)(x - y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |^{2}$$
for all $x, y \in (a, b)$.

(Hint: Consider $\varphi(t) = f(y + t(x - y))$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.)

---

The inequalities reminded me of one of theorems in Mean Value Theorem chapter:

---

**Theorem**: If $f$ is a real continuous function on $[a, b]$ which is differentiable in $(a, b)$, then there is a point $x \in (a, b)$ at which
$$f(b) - f(a) = (b - a)f'(x)$$

---

So, for some $c \in [x,y]$,
\begin{align}
\left | f(x)-f(y)-f'(x)(x-y) \right | &= \left | f'(c)(x-y)-f'(x)(x-y) \right | = \left | f'(c)-f'(x) \right| \times \left | x-y \right | \\
&\leq |c-x| |x-y| \leq |x-y|^2
\end{align}

Is that a correct way to solve this?

I mean, I didn't even had to use the hint in any way.
The hint seems to suggest to use the definition of a derivative, with $\varphi(t) = f(y + t(x - y))$, where $0 \leq t \leq 1$, but frankly,  I have no idea where does $0 \leq t \leq 1$ come from and how to apply it.

Comment: Is this problem before the MVT chapter? If so, then you might not "be able" to use the MVT in the sense that you supposedly haven't learned it yet. Otherwise, it seems correct.

Comment: Nope, it's after the MVT chapter.